# Drupal 7 - Adding second level menu on the side bar to a particular section

Tags: drupal-7

I'd like to add a second level menu **on the side bar** to a particular content within a menu.

I would have top level menus, **Home**, **About Us**, **Resources**. What would be the best practice to have the second level menu to appear only in **Resources** section not in any other sections?

Can I have a customisation at menu level, eg only for pages under *resources*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules mentioned by fotuzlab may help you or you may have a theme that already implements some levels of drop down menus/expandable menus.  But for some of these modules/themes may require that you check the box for `Show as expanded` in the menu link setting for **Resources** and **unckeck for the other menu links**  .

[image]

And just to add another possible module, you can check out [Menu Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block).

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I meant to ask on how to create the second level menu on the side bar only for a particular menu item. Do you have any idea how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[SuperFish Menu](http://drupal.org/project/superfish)

This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many contributed modules for the same.
Try:

http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus

http://drupal.org/project/jquerymenu

http://drupal.org/project/superfish

or you can checkout the comparison of different drupal dropdown menus here:

http://drupal.org/node/990154

Comment: Thanks for the module suggestions, but I am not looking for a module but instead how to make the menu appears only in resources area.

Comment: Even for that you need to use a drop down menu from above.
Let Home, About us and Resources be the parent items. Now add children items below resources. When you browse the menu, only parent with child items would feature the drop down. Check this image for clarity http://drupal.org/files/images/nice_menus.png

Comment: Sorry I guess my question was not clear. I meant to add a second level menu in the side bar. I will update the questions

Answer (score 0):

The Menu Block module will allow you to choose a source menu, menu level, e.g. 2nd level, and display it as a block anywhere on the page: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block